# how to setup elasticsearch to concurrently handle 20k POST request?

Tags: elasticsearch

we are trying to collect performance metric from about 20k servers and POST the data to elasticsearch using the below curl command to analyse the data further

```
curl 
   -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_URL/sariovm/sar/" 
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  
   -d '{ "@timestamp" : '\""$DATE3\""', "cpu" : '$cpu', "iowait" : '$iowait', "swapips" : '$swapips', "swapops" : '$swapops', "hostname" : "'$HOSTNAME'" }'
```

currently we tested it using 80+ POST request to elasticsearch and we have setup only single node to handle the request. How to setup elasticsearch to scale to handle 20K+ POST requests?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are tracking 20k server metrics, it should be 20k requests per second since you want to aggregate without having an exact frequency in your use case, 20k servers sending CPU usage could happen all in the same time, why not.

You need to benchmark, and you should start with the default deployment, 3 nodes,1 master, green cluster, read more about what means the elasticsearch [types of nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html), special attention to data node and ingestion node, in conclusion you need to start with the default deployment and benchmark, tune and keep benchmarking since every use case is special, yours looks like one where elasticsearch has made a great product for, read about beats, logstash and kibana.

In my personal opinion, if you don't have too much budget and you don't care about real real-time there are some other ways to handle this, like storing the 20k metrics per second in Kafka which is great to handle high io writing capacity, then [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) it to elasticsearch at the capacity your cluster supports, obviously this adds Kafka to your royal pains, problems we like because we know there is always a solution and fun times.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends.
20K+ posts per what? Per second? Per hour? Per day? you'll need that information.
Also, by using a single node you're ignoring the biggest elasticsearch advantage to my opinion (which is, of course, the support of scaling out).
It also depends on the size of your post.
You'll need a lot more information to answer this question, but what I recommend (and what elastic recommends) is to simply try. Use some node and start trying and indexing,
and add resources until you reach your goal